# Unable to subscribe angular service method in component

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

I want to call a component method with interval condition from my service. I'm trying to do with rxjs observable but somehow could not able to do the subscription for service observable in the component please help me what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance.
here is my service and component code snippets.

**Service**:

```
private dateArray$: Subject < any > ;
public obserableObjects: {
  setDateWatch$: Observable < any > ;
};
constructor() {
  this.dateArray$ = new Subject < any > ();
  this.obserableObjects = {
    setDateWatch$: this.setDateWatch$.asObservable()
  };
);
public initservice() {
  this.dateArray$.next('test');
}
```

**Component:**

```
   private dateInf$: Observable<any>;
   constructor() {
      @Inject(Service) private service: Service) {
      this.dateInf$ = this.service.obserableObjects.setDateWatch$;
      console.log(this.dateInf$);
      console.log("***********************************");
      this.dateInf$.subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
```

Comment: It seems like your service constructor does not set the object right:     `setDateWatch$: this.setDateWatch$.asObservable()` instead of `    setDateWatch$: this.dateArray$.asObservable()`. Your component registers to an observable that never gets any value pushed into it.

Comment: That still did not solve the issue, still subscribe is not getting called.I Have changed to 'setDateWatch$: this.dateArray$.asObservable()'

Comment: The subscribe or the handler?

Comment: I've updated obervable definition as per your suggestion, but that still unable to invoke component subscription.

Comment: I think I know what it is, you subscribe after the value is emitted. Try changing teh dateArray$ from `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject` or to a `ReplaySubject` with a size of 1

Answer (score 0):

You have one error as @Meir pointed out; in the service constructor, change

```
setDateWatch$: this.setDateWatch$.asObservable()
```

to

```
setDateWatch$: this.dateArray$.asObservable()
```

Now everything is wired properly. You still don't see any output because nothing is ever pushed into the `Subject`.  So add the following line to the bottom of your component constructor, or anywhere after you've subscribed:

```
this.service.initService();
```